# Packets received real time in Linux but slow in windows (UDP protocol)

Tags: c#, c, sockets, network-programming, udp

I have a server which sends a counter to a client using UDP protocol. Code snippets for server and client are below..

I print the count which I send on server side and also print the count which I receive on the client

When server is Linux and client is Linux, I get the data(the count) in real time without delay. However when I tested the client with windows machine, The counter in the client side lags way behind the counter in the server side.

Can anybody provide any pointers as to what the problem could be

```
/////////
//SERVER.c (C Language)
//////// 
 portno = 11000;
  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR opening socket");
  optval = 1;
  setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 
         (const void *)&optval , sizeof(int));


//set server address
    bzero((char *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
     serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  inet_aton("192.168.139.248", &serveraddr.sin_addr);
  serveraddr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)portno);

  //get data from client and store clientaddr
   bzero(buf, BUFSIZE);
    n = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0,
         (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, &clientlen);

 //keep sending a counter to client using &clientaddr in infinite loop
int ct = 0;
  while (1) {
    ct++;
    sprintf(buf,"%d",ct);
    n = sendto(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0, 
           (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, clientlen);
    printf("server sent %s\n",  buf);
  }


/////////
//CLIENT.cs  (CSHARP)
//////// 

main()
{
    done = false;
    listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
    IPAddress sender = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.139.248");
    groupEP = new IPEndPoint(sender,listenPort);
    robotCommThread = new Thread (receiveThread);
    if (!robotCommThread.IsAlive)
        robotCommThread.Start ();
}


void receiveThread(){
    int ct = 0;
    Debug.Log("Received broadcast Start");
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ct.ToString());
    listener.Send(data,data.Length, groupEP);
//listener.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 100);
    while(true){

        byte[] bytes = listener.Receive( ref groupEP);
        Debug.Log("Received broadcast" +System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Comment: It could be that your logging mechanism isn't fast enough in Windows to keep up.  Try only logging every 1000th message or something (e.g. if ((++someCounter%1000)==0) Debug.Log("Received broadcast"); ) and see if the client is able to keep up then.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I tried logging every 10000 the message and it actually  does not lag. Logging mechanism is the reason. Thanks for the Debugging. Was searching all weird stuff to solve. Can you put it as an answer?